# JSON and location distance calculate

Tags: android, json, location, distance

I am planning this. First device get all location and info from json. Json includes latitude and longitude. After, calculate every items distance to device. If it is less than x number show it in list view. I have used to use json parsing and list view which is basic.

And here is code for location calculate

```
Location locationA = new     Location("point A");
locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);
Location     locationB = new Location("point B");
 locationB.setLatitude(latB);
 locationB.setLongitude(lngB);
 float     distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

I will use this code.

I think it will be like this.
Get json items. Before but it on the list check distance if it is lover than x put it in list else return getting json item

I need some codes for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the code for calculate distance from two points with coordinates?
I make something like this with a web page.
You can save all coordinates into a DataBase, when you have the phone position you can take back all coordinates near your position (like a filter).
After that you can use your code for check witch coordinates are inside your range X and put it into a class that contain your coordinates.

Your coordinates class:

```
public class Coordinates {

private double _lat;
private double _lng;


//Empty constructor
public Coordinates(){

}
//Constructor
public Coordinates(int id, double lat, double lng){
    this._lat = lat;
    this._lng = lng;
}
// constructor
public Materia(double lat, double lng){
    this._lat = lat;
    this._lng = lng;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

//getting latitude
public int getLat(){

    return this._lat;

}
//setting color
public void setLat(double lat){

    this._lat = lat;

}
//getting longitude
public Double getLng() {

    return this._lng;

}
//setting longitude
 public void setLng(Double lng) {

     this._lng = lng;

 }
}
```

Your Database Sqlite:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "coordinates.db";
//Materie table name
public static final String TABLE_COORDINATES = "coordinates";
//coordinates columns table names
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "latitude";
public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "longitude";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
onCreate(){}
onUpdate(){}
//Other methods that you need

//Here something like
// Getting All Coordinates
public List<Coordinate> getAllCoordinate() {
    List<Coordinate> coordinateList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COORDINATES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
            coordinate.setID(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0)));
            coordinate.setLat(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1)));
            coordinate.setLng(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
            // Adding contact to list
           coordinateList.add(coordinate);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return coordinate list
    return coordinateList;
}
```

With the getAllCoordinate you take all coordinate in your database and generate an array of object that you can read with a for and access the single `lat` and `lng`.
Maybe the code is not perfect if you use that take care for some errors.
[Here a good guide for database](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)